# $L_\infty$ norm from $L_2$

Tags: real-analysis

If $\mu$ is any measure on $\mathcal{X}$, and say $\hat{f}$ is some random approximation of $f^*$, then does $$\sqrt{\int |\hat{f}(x)-f^*(x)|^2\, d\mu(x)} \leq \epsilon$$ with probability atleast $1-\delta$ implies that $$||\hat{f} - f^* ||_{\infty} \leq \epsilon$$ with probability at least $1-\delta$?

I was thinking this is correct because we could choose $\mu$ to be a dirac measure at each state and hence convergence in $L_2$ for any measure implies convergence in $L_\infty$.

Comment: You mean the bounds hold independent of $\mu$?

Comment: Yes, looks like it

Comment: I think this problem needs to be properly posed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'hardest' part of this question is coming up with a technical framework to deal with it, and I suppose this is also what you think.
After all, you already have an intuition on how to solve it.
That said, the technical difficulties, in particular those related to the measurability of sets/functions, are nontrivial, especially because the question says so little about the underlying spaces.

I will set aside these (rather important) questions but encourage you to tackle them $($are the $X_\mu$ actually measurable functions, and hence random variable? is $\left\{f\in F(\Omega,\mathbb{K})\, ; \, \lVert f-f^*\rVert_\infty>\epsilon \right\}$ a measurable set? etc$)$.

---

Let $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\mathcal{X}=(\Omega,\Sigma_\mathcal{X})$ be a measurable space.
Let $\mathcal{F}=(F(\Omega,\mathbb{K}), \Sigma_\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space on some set of functions $f:\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{K}$ we denote by $F(\Omega,\mathbb{K})$.

Fix some $f^*\in F(\Omega,\mathbb{K})$ and consider for each measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{X}$ the random variable $X_\mu:F(\Omega,\mathbb{K})\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$X_\mu\left(f\right)=\sqrt{\int_\Omega |f(x)-f^*(x)|^2\, d\mu}.$$

For $x\in \Omega$, let $\delta(x)$ be the Dirac measure over $x$ on $\Omega$. Then

$$X_{\delta(x)}\left(f\right)=|f(x)-f^*(x)|$$

In this case:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left(X_{\delta(x)} >\epsilon \right)
&=
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{f\in F(\Omega,\mathbb{K})\, ; \, X_{\delta(x)}(f)>\epsilon \right\}\right)\\
&=
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{f\in F(\Omega,\mathbb{K})\, ; \, |f(x)-f^*(x)|>\epsilon \right\}\right)
\end{align}

---

Now, suppose that, $\mathcal{X}$ is endowed with a particular measure $\mu_\mathcal{X}$, so that for $f\in F(\Omega,\mathbb{K})$ we may define

$$\lVert f \rVert_\infty =\inf\left\{C\in\mathbb{R}\, ; \, \mu_\mathcal{X}\left(f^{-1}(C,\infty)\right)=0\right\}.$$

Suppose also that we have $\lVert f-f^*\rVert_\infty>\epsilon$ with probability $p>0$, meaning

$$p=
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{f\in F(\Omega,\mathbb{K})\, ; \, \lVert f-f^*\rVert_\infty>\epsilon \right\}\right).$$

Then for any $z\in\Omega$ we have

\begin{align}
p
&=
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{f\in F(\Omega,\mathbb{K})\, ; \, \exists c>0,\, \mu_\mathcal{X}\left(\{x\in \Omega\,;\, |f(x)-f^*(x)|>\epsilon + c \right\}\right)>0\right)\\
&\geq
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{f\in F(\Omega,\mathbb{K})\, ; \, \exists c>0,\, \exists x \in \Omega,\, |f(x)-f^*(x)|>\epsilon + c \right\}\right)\\
&=
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{f\in F(\Omega,\mathbb{K})\, ; \, \exists x \in \Omega,\, |f(x)-f^*(x)|>\epsilon \right\}\right)\\
&\geq
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\{f\in F(\Omega,\mathbb{K})\, ; \, |f(z)-f^*(z)|>\epsilon \right\}\right)\\
&=
\mathbb{P}\left(X_{\delta(z)}>\epsilon\right)
\end{align}

It follows that

$$\mathbb{P}\left(X_{\delta(z)}\leq\epsilon\right)=1-\mathbb{P}\left(X_{\delta(z)}>\epsilon\right)\leq 1-p$$

---

Now, suppose that $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{\mu}\leq\epsilon\right)\geq 1-\delta$ for all $\mu$ (and in particular for the Dirac measures), as per our hypotheses.
Then we have that for all $z\in\Omega$

$$1-\delta \leq \mathbb{P}\left(X_{\delta(z)}>\epsilon\right)\leq 1-p.$$

Since the probability that $\lVert f-f^*\rVert_\infty\leq\epsilon$ is $1-p$, it follows that it is at least $1-\delta$, as desired.